# Send notification on onesignal

Tags: android, cordova, onesignal, phonegap

I want to send notification to my android app via OneSignal, whats wrong in this code ?

He is not working, i'm already read all documentation and dont know what i need to do.

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
  var notificationObj = { contents: {en: "message body"},
                          include_player_ids: [ids.userId]};
  window.plugins.OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
    function(successResponse) {
      console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
    },
    function (failedResponse) {
      console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
      alert("Notification Post Failed:\n" + JSON.stringify(failedResponse));
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'it is not working'? What is the current result?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined